# Is it reasonable to use my own private npm like Sinopia or is there an easier/better way?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

(Question is being recorded for future use)

I am not very familiar with node js and am unsure if I should be using a private npm repository when using fabric composer

Answer (score 1):

When installing fabric composer for use with a nodejs application, you should run `npm install -S composer-client` or `npm install -S composer-admin`, both of which will be pulled down from the public npm repository.

If you wish to publish a business network definition (model and/or transaction processor functions) to npm, you can either use the public npm repository if you want the code to be shared with the community, or you may opt for a private enterprise npm repository if you do not.

Other than them two use cases, there isn't a need to publish a business network definition to a local npm server like sinopia as you will not be sharing. However, if you do identify a use case to do this, sinopia will work fine.

Its also worth noting, that you can use `npm link` (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) to access an npm module you have written on your system, in other projects, without publishing to an npm server.